# Laravel 5 Blade - strange occurence in foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a collection which I am displaying below as an array to make it easier to view.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => 6
    "name" => "food"
    "value" => "T1 M1"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => 7
    "name" => "drink"
    "value" => ""
  ]
  2 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => 8
    "name" => "drink"
    "value" => "A1 P1"
  ]
]
```

Within my view I am doing something like the following

```
<div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
    @foreach($party->partyOptions as $id => $data)
        @if ($data->name === 'food')
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <label>Number of food {{ $id + 1 }}:</label>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
    @foreach($party->partyOptions as $id => $data)
        @if ($data->name === 'drink')
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <label>Number of drink {{ $id + 1 }}:</label>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I do different loops for the types because I am doing some additional stuff which I have not shown above.
Anyways, with the above, I would expect the first div to display

```
Number of food 1
```

And the second div to display

```
Number of drink 1
Number of drink 2
```

This is not the case however.  Instead, it continues the id count, so what I get outputted is

```
Number of food 1

Number of drink 2
Number of drink 3
```

If I have more names I am searching for, the number continues.

Why would this be happening?  Shouldnt the id get reset for each loop?

Any information regarding this appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you are selecting the index (var name id) of the collection, so you can see that it starts at `1` for the first drink and then `2` for the second group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the index of the collection, not of the iteration.

To get the index you want, create a new collection that is filtered to just what you want:

```php
<div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
    @foreach($party->partyOptions->where('name', 'food')->values() as $id => $data)
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Number of food {{ $id + 1 }}:</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
    @foreach($party->partyOptions->where('name', 'drink')->values() as $id => $data)
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Number of drink {{ $id + 1 }}:</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Clearly explained and refactored using the framework's tools. +1.

Comment: Why do you assume It's Eloquent?

Comment: @Kocik - I don't. There's nothing in my code snippet that assumes Eloquent.

Comment: [The base Support collection has a `where` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f363857d2fce4608dca7de0b9421fdb5b3bd16f5/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L214-L228).

Comment: I didn't notice that it's collection type :)

Answer (score 1):

Loop behavior is perfectly normal. Your`$id` is index in the array you are iterating. 
See documantation: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

So in your array you have "drink" under indexes `1` and `2`. You need different approach - you need separate variable that you increment inside if block:

```
<div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
{{$i = 0}}
    @foreach($party->partyOptions as $id => $data)
        @if ($data->name === 'drink')
            {{$i ++}}
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <label>Number of drink {{ $i }}:</label>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```